# Apply a JavaScript function using string name of the function

Tags: javascript, function, apply

Is that possible to apply a custom to a JavaScript variable using the a JavaScript String variable, example :

```
app.get(param1, callback)
```

I'd like to be able to parameterize 'get' as a string,
and something like :

```
let verb = 'get'
app['verb'](param1, callback)
```

doesn't seem to work properly.

Is there a way to do that in JavaScript ?

Comment: `app[verb]`, otherwise it will execute `app.verb(param1, callback)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `app[verb]`, without quotes, otherwise you're passing a string `"verb"`, not the value of the `verb` variable. Here is the example with function nested in object (very close to your case):

```js
const app = {get: function(param1, param2) { console.log(`Param1: ${param1}, Param2: ${param2}`) }}
let verb = 'get'
app[verb](1, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, since `verb` is a variable you shouldn't put it in quotes `'`

```
let verb = 'get'
app[verb](param1, callback)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
app['verb'](params);
```

tries to invoke a function called 'verb'.

what you want is :

```
let verb = 'get';
app[verb](param1, callback);
```